# POST a new json object to Mongodb by changing objectId

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have a web service that gets an object from mongodb, displays it as json, allows the user to edit the object then save the object back. I am trying to implement a "Save as" button to post allow the user to make changes to the object and then save it back as a new object. The problem is since the objectId is not changing when I do the POST request the object just overwrites the preexisting object with the same objectId.

Is there a way to assign a new objectId in javascript?

The implementation is done with the mongodb c# driver on a wcf service.

Comment: By the way: I hope that when you save a document under an existing ObjectId, you first validate on the server that the user actually owns the existing document and doesn't attempt to overwrite an object owned by someone else.

Comment: @Philipp this is not a multi user type of case. There is only one collection and database in play at a given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attempt to [replicate the algorithm which is used for ObjectID generation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), but there is an easier way to do that. When you just remove the _id from the document, MongoDB will create a new one and save it under this. You can do this with the javascript delete keyword:

```
delete yourDocument._id;
```

Alternatively you can do it on the C# side by generating a new _id for the document before you save it:

```
yourDocument.Set("_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId());
```

Comment: What I ended up doing is just taking the object from my service and doing `myObject.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();` essentially what you said. I don't think I did a very good job of explaining the problem. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

No you can not change or remove the `_id` field from the mongodb document. This is because `_id` serves as a primary key and [therefore is immutable](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-primary-key). If you really want to change the _id of the document, you need to remove this document and copy it's content to a new one with the new `_id`.

P.S. I am talking here about _id field. If you want to change any other field, which for some reason happened to have ObjectId data, you can do this.

Comment: I think you haven't understood the question correctly. He wants to save the data as a new document while also retaining the document with the old data. Therefor he has to insert the data with a new _id, so the document of the old _id isn't overwritten.

Comment: Are you sure that he wants it? Because I see "allows the user to edit the object then save the object back". I do not see anywhere that he wants to have a copy of the previous data. But may be I really did not get a question.

Comment: "the problem is since the objectId is not changing when I do the POST request the object just overwrites the preexisting object with the same objectId." this clearly says that he does **not** want to lose the previous data.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Philipp has it right. Thanks for your help though.